# Typescript conditional return interface based on input enums

Tags: typescript, enums, conditional-types

Requirement is to provide an array of enums as an argument to define the return type interface. Based on these enum attributes `Key.A` and or `Key.B` the return type interface should contain `A1` and or `B1` with attribute keys (like enum keys) `A` and or `B`.

Pre-Setup looks like the following:

```ts
import { parse } from 'someWhere'; \\ will capitalize config first-lvl attributes

enum Key {
  A = "a",
  B = "b",
}

interface A1 {
  x: string;
}

interface B1 {
  y: string;
}

type FF = {
  A: A1;
  B: B1;
};

type Conf = <???>???;

const Fn = <E extends Key>(key: E[], config: unknown): Conf<E> => {
  return parse.JSON(key, config) as Conf<E>;
};
```

Outcome should be that `Fn` is called with some enum values and the returned interface only contains the corresponding attributes like:

```ts
const config = '{ "b": { "y": "some string" } }';

const res = Fn([Key.B], config);

console.log(res.B.y) // 'some string'
console.log(res.A.x) // Type Error: Property 'A' does not exist on type
```

based on that I tried the following:

```ts
type Conf<E extends Key> = {
  [K in keyof typeof Key]: K extends E[keyof E] ? FF[K] : never;
};

const res = Fn([Key.B]);
```

With this implementation all attributes of Key exist in `res`:

[Return Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTifU.png)

The second approach was to define Conf like

```ts
type Conf<E extends Key> = {
  [K in E]: K extends E[keyof E] ? FF : never;
};
```

Only attribute `b` exists in return interface but I couldn't find out how to index `FF` to select the correct interface based on the enum => `B1`. Additionally the resulting interface is `res.b.` rather than `res.B.`

[Return Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghxJJ.png)

Comment: Please include actual code in the post as opposed to linking to pictures of code; code links can break over time and text in image form cannot be searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really tricky because `Key.B`, `"B"` and `"b"` are all different.

If you are willing to rewrite your map `FF` such that it is keyed by the actual enum values `"a"` and `"b"` rather than the enum property names, it becomes trivially simple.  You can just use `Pick<FF, E>` to get the return type.

```
type FF = {
  a: A1;
  b: B1;
};

const fn = <E extends Key>(key: E[], config?: unknown): Pick<FF, E> => {
  return parse.JSON(key, config) as Pick<FF, E>;
};

const res1: {b: B1} = fn([Key.B]);
const res2: {a: A1} = fn([Key.A]);
const res3: {a: A1, b: B1} = fn([Key.A, Key.B]);
```

Otherwise I can't quite make sense of it either.

Comment: If there isn't another solution, then this will work for me. The problem with the actual enum values is that these values contains hyphen formatted strings like `some-key`. This will make the handling of `res` a bit ugly like `res1['some-key'].y` or `res1.[Key.B].y`